# Is this practice of manually applying scopes standard C?

Tags: c, scope, curly-braces

Is creating local scopes with just a pair of brackets, would that be considered standard C?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    {
        register char x = 'a';
        putchar(x); // works
    }
    //putchar(x); wont work
}
```

Or is it best to not use this? Is it a GCC compiler extension?

I have once been told that the accepted practice is a `do {...} while (0);` loop. Is it true that all C compilers will recognise this practice just like it is safe to assume any given C compiler will recognise an `if` statement?

I tried googling this, and my results were about scope behavior, and had nothing to do with manually applying scopes.

Comment: Yes, it is standard. And has always been standard.

Comment: Many people consider *not* creating a scope after `if` or `while` to be bad practice.

Comment: Yes, but honestly, you should really have made the effort to consult a C language book before asking such a basic question.

Comment: You should not see the `do … while (0)` thing in vanilla code, just in `#define` directives. [It is a kludge for macros.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/why-use-apparently-meaningless-do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-macros)

Comment: Yes, It's even K&R standard.  If you look even in the first edition of "The C programming language" by Brian Kernighan and Denis Ritchie, you'll find that a pair of brackets means a block, in which you can start declaring new objects as you do at the beginning of `main()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is standard; this is creation of block scope, as supported by C language.

Regarding "best to use" part, it depends, certainly it might be a bit confusing to some people.

This might come in very useful with *generated* code though, so you don't need to bother (as much) with unique identifiers for local vars:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  {
    int x = 4;
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }
  {
    int x = 5;
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }
}
```

Comment: *"Certainly you wouldn't be capable of doing something like"* - what do you mean by that? You just did it...

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: He means, wouldn't be able to do this without the brackets.

Comment: @einpoklum huh, makes sense.

Comment: that was a bit weird phrasing to be honest

Comment: My question is, is it some compiler extension or standard C?

Comment: @0x10 it's standard C

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is standard; you can always introduce a new scope with an extra pair of `{}`

I often use it in conditionally compiled code, to avoid unused variable warnings:

---

```
#if DEBUG
    {
    struct node *tmp;
    for (tmp=this; tmp; tmp= tmp->next) {
        printf(stderr, "Node %u: %s\n", tmp->num, tmp->name);
        }
     }
#endif
```

Comment: In macros do{ "your code"} while (0) is often used to force the semicolon after the marco (Make sure that the marco behavious like a function). I know this is not part of the question but I thought its worth to mention it.

Comment: I know the *funky* `do {...} while(0)` macro, but that was not part of the question (and will only cause confusion, IMHO)

Comment: How about `for (struct node *tmp=this; tmp; tmp= tmp->next) { /* ... */ }`?

Answer (score 2):

This is standard C.

Section 6.8p1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) gives the following syntax for a statement:

> ```
> statement:
>   labeled-statement
>   compound-statement
>   expression-statement
>   selection-statement
>   iteration-statement
>   jump-statement
> ```

Where a `compound-statement` is defined in section 6.8.2p1:

> ```
> compound-statement:
>    { block-item-list(opt) }
>
> block-item-list:
>   block-item
>   block-item-list block-item
>
> block-item:
>   declaration
>   statement
> ```

What this says is that anyplace that a statement can occur, a compound statement (i.e. a set of statements surrounded by `{}`) can occur.

Comment: I don't quite understand the `code` that you provided.

Comment: It is part of the syntax definition. You can find it in the back of K&R, for instance.